# Différence entre « orgueil » et « fierté »

Tags: synonymes

Quelle est la différence ente orgueil et fierté?

J'ai toujours eu l'impression qu'« orgueil » avait un connotation négative contrairement à « fierté »: « Je suis fier de mon travail. », « L'orgueil est un péché. »

Mais je n'ai trouvé aucune source pour appuyer ma thèse.

[Le Larousse définit même fierté](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fiert%C3%A9/): « Sentiment d'orgueil, de satisfaction légitime de soi »

Comment: [Fierté](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9F0709), [Orgueil](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9O0717)

Comment: Orgueil (orgueilleux) est un peu plus péjoratif que fierté (fier). Le caractère péjoratif de fierté dépend du contexte. Si je dis que je suis fier de mon travail, ce n'est pas péjoratif, du moins de mon point de vue. Le mot orgueil est toujours péjoratif.

Comment: @Damien l'orgueil est d'ailleurs [un des sept péchés capitaux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9ch%C3%A9_capital).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: https://femmedinfluence.fr/differences-entre-la-fierte-et-lorgueil/

> Dans la fierté on dénote un sentiment noble, un sentiment élevé et ce sans même l’avoir provoqué puisque derrière se cache une sorte d’humilité.
>
> Contrairement à l’orgueil que l’on peut comparer à la vanité ou à la mise en concurrence avec autrui, d’où la fameuse expression “être piqué dans son orgueil”.

Also here: https://fr.vikidia.org/wiki/Fiert%C3%A9

> La fierté est une forme de confiance en soi, un état d'esprit dans lequel se trouve une personne qui pense connaître ses capacités et les estime bonnes. Une personne fière pourra paraître prétentieuse car elle déclarera facilement être capable de faire de grandes choses, mais ne se compare pas nécessairement aux autres.
>
> La différence entre fierté et orgueil est petite. On pourrait dire que la fierté, c'est la confiance dans le fait qu'on peut faire les choses bien ; tandis que l'orgueil c'est la confiance dans le fait qu'on peut faire les choses mieux que les autres.

Comment: Il y a aussi un contexte social : « Eh, dit-donc, il est pas un peu *fier* le Dédé ? — Bah, laisse tomber, "il pète plus haut qu’son cul". » C’est comme cela que certains expriment leur vision des choses, sans langue de bois et avec un bon sens pratique que dénote la ‘langue verte’, imagée mais non vulgaire.

Comment: Alors qu’un Compagnon du Devoir *(https://www.compagnons-du-devoir.com/ )* ne peut être que fier d’avoir son art (la technique maîtrisée jusqu’à la Beauté) reconnu par ses pairs, ce qui inclus les qualités morales dont celle de l’effacement de soi devant l’œuvre (la signature est cachée, et si elle est imitée, d’autres signes secrets révèleront l’imposture). C’est la *fierté/force* de l’homme libre et accompli.

Comment: … — Et *L’orgueil* ? — La *fierté* de la conscience cannibalisée par l’ego.

Answer (score 0):

Votre appréhension de l'idée d'assez grande  généralité que le mot « orgueil » est associé à des caractéristiques inférieures de l'esprit alors que le mot « fierté » ne l'est pas  et concerne des sphères d'une certaine élévation de l'esprit, ne créera pas de contestation parmi la plupart des personnes familières avec le français. Cependant voilà deux mots qui regrettablement n'ont pas eu une assignation particulièrement heureuse dans le domaine des concepts: chacun est   utilisé pour signifier ce que l'on peut faire dire à l'autre; on peut néanmoins dire que chacun ne déborde pas excessivement de sa « région principale ».

**I** Commençons par « orgueil ». Une première  définition générale que l'on extrait du TLFi nous laisse sans le moindre doute que ce mot est utilisé pour nommer ce que certains appellent un [vice](https://www.furet.com/livres/l-orgueil-et-l-admiration-de-soi-lyess-chacal-9782956430728.html), un défaut ([Marc Gourion](http://marcgourion26.blogspot.com/2018/12/lorgueil.html)).

- [I. A.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/orgueil) Présomption, estime exagérée, amour excessif de soi-même, qui fait que l'on est persuadé de sa propre excellence, que l'on se juge supérieur aux autres.

Si on s'attarde sur les acceptions particulières qui tombent sous le coup de cette définition on voit que l'une des facettes du concept a des origines culturelles profondes, cela si l'on s'attache à considérer la religion comme élément de culture, et des implications que l'on devra appeler
« scientifico-culturelles »  modernes ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychologie#La_psychologie_est-elle_scientifique_?)), cela si l'on ne peut toujours pas croire que les problèmes que pose l'âme relèvent strictement d'une question de science pure, tout au moins d'une telle science que nous connaissions.

- [2. MOR., RELIG.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/orgueil) Défaut, esprit, vice d'orgueil; infernal, maudit, noir orgueil. Orgueil et humilité s'opposent donc comme le non et le oui, − celui-là qui est l'esprit de refus, la mortelle satisfaction d'une âme endurcie, blindée, cuirassée de contentement et entièrement insensible aux valeurs (Jankélévitch,Les Vertus et l'Amour,1970, p.661):
  Le problème métaphysique de l'orgueil, de l'hybris, que les Grecs ont aperçu (...) a été un des thèmes essentiels de la théologie chrétienne (...). L'orgueil consiste à ne trouver sa force qu'en soi, il retranche celui qui l'éprouve d'une certaine communion des êtres, du même coup il tend à la briser, il joue comme un principe de destruction. G. Marcel,Position et approches concrètes du mystère ontologique,1967, p.74.
  ♦ [P. réf. à la Bible, Prov. 16-18] Orgueil de Lucifer, de Satan. Isaïe compare le roi de Babylone à Lucifer, qui est tombé du ciel sur terre à cause de son orgueil (Théol. cath.t.4, 11920, p.361).
  ♦ Péché d'orgueil. Le premier des sept péchés capitaux.
- [1. PSYCHANAL.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/orgueil) ,,Hypertrophie du Moi et surestimation personnelle`` (Pel. Psych. 1976). L'orgueil (...) est un des éléments de la constitution paranoïaque et il fait le lit de la méfiance, de l'interprétation et des idées de persécution (Lafon1963).

« Orgueil » est donc le terme qui qualifie l'état d'esprit caractéristique des puissances du mal, c'est le terme qui nomme le premier des péchés capitaux, le terme qui parle de la tendance qu'a l'esprit humain en proie à ses propres surestimations de lui-même a vouloir s'imposer sur son environnement.

**II** « Fierté », dans ses provinces principales de caractérisation des concepts a sans conteste une place beaucoup plus élevée.

- [II.− Usuel. [À propos d'une pers.] A.− Laudatif](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiert%C3%A9)
  1 Souci de sa dignité, respect de soi-même. Fierté de l'âme, du caractère. Synon. amour-propre, dignité, noblesse.
  2 Satisfaction d'amour-propre fondée. Synon. contentement, orgueil.

**III** Dans une partie subséquente de l'entrée « orgueil » du TLFi on trouve la définition déroutante suivante.

- [**I** B.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/orgueil) Fierté, sentiment noble inspiré par une juste confiance, l'estime légitime de soi ou des autres. Orgueil maternel, national; noble, respectable orgueil; donner de l'orgueil à qqn.

La comparaison avec la définition au **II** montre donc qu'« orgueil » perd ses connotations négatives et connote fortement les concepts que l'on identifie sous le nom de fierté: estime légitime (et non plus éxagérée), noblesse.

De même, « fierté » comporte une acception assez contradictoire; personnellement, je ressens toujours l'effet de cet usage comme très désagréable.

- [B.− Péj.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiert%C3%A9) Défaut d'une personne qui affiche une supériorité illusoire, qui affecte des airs hautains et méprisants. Synon. arrogance, dédain.
  Malhabile à se faire aimer, ou plutôt ne le cherchant guère, par misanthropie, dédain, fierté (Gide, Journal,1927, p. 850).Les deux jeunes dames, un peu raidies, se tenaient à l'écart, non par fierté, comme le croyait Joséfa, mais parce qu'elles hésitaient sur l'attitude à prendre (Mauriac, Myst. Frontenac,1933, p. 254)

Cette définition est peu différente de celle de l'orgueil (**I** I.A) : La « Présomption, estime exagérée, amour excessif de soi-même, qui fait que l'on est persuadé de sa propre excellence, que l'on se juge supérieur aux autres » doit presque toujours transparaitre dans une phase ou une autre du comportement, être « affichée » en quelque sorte pour être reconnue; c'est donc le « *défaut d'une personne qui affiche une supériorité illusoire* », si pas  extérieurement du moins à elle-même dans leur for intérieur.

**IV** Dans un article de [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgueil#Diff%C3%A9rence_entre_orgueil_et_vanit%C3%A9) on peut vérifier que les provinces principales de ces deux termes sont telles que décrites ci-dessus.

- L'orgueil (superbia en latin) est une opinion très avantageuse, le plus souvent exagérée, qu'on a de sa valeur personnelle aux dépens de la considération due à autrui, à la différence de la fierté  qui n'a nul besoin de se mesurer à l'autre ni de le rabaisser.

Dans la définition de l'orgueil telle que donnée par le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/orgueil) on trouve la profonde caractérisation suivante de l'orgueil.

- O détestable orgueil ! Non il n’est point de vice
  Plus funeste aux mortels, plus digne de supplice.
  Voulant tout asservir à ses injustes droits,
  De l’humanité même il étouffe la voix. — (Philippe Néricault Destouches, Le Glorieux, Lycante, Acte IV, sc.3)